# scipy is not optimizing and returns "Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss"

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy

I have the following code which attempts to minimize a log likelihood function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def loglikelihood(params, data):
    (mu, alpha, beta) = params
    tlist = np.array(data)
    r = np.zeros(len(tlist))
    for i in xrange(1,len(tlist)):
        r[i] = math.exp(-beta*(tlist[i]-tlist[i-1]))*(1+r[i-1])
    loglik  = -tlist[-1]*mu
    loglik = loglik+alpha/beta*sum(np.exp(-beta*(tlist[-1]-tlist))-1)
    loglik = loglik+np.sum(np.log(mu+alpha*r))
    return -loglik

atimes = [ 148.98894201,  149.70253172,  151.13717804,  160.35968355,
        160.98322609,  161.21331798,  163.60755544,  163.68994973,
        164.26131871,  228.79436067]
a= 0.01
alpha = 0.5
beta = 0.6
print loglikelihood((a, alpha, beta), atimes)

res = minimize(loglikelihood, (0.01, 0.1,0.1), method = 'BFGS',args = (atimes,))
print res
```

It gives me

```
28.3136498357
./test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  loglik = loglik+np.sum(np.log(mu+alpha*r))
   status: 2
  success: False
     njev: 14
     nfev: 72
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
      fun: 32.131359359964378
        x: array([ 0.01,  0.1 ,  0.1 ])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
      jac: array([ -2.8051672 ,  13.06962156, -48.97879982])
```

Notice that it hasn't managed to optimize the parameters at all and the minimized value 32 is bigger than 28 which is what you get with    a= 0.01, alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.6 .   It's possible this problem could be avoided by choosing better initial guesses but if so, how can I do this automatically?

---

Nelder-Mead, TNC and SLSQP work as drop-in replacements. None of the other methods do.

Comment: I would think you'd want to maximize LL, not minimize it. If you're minimizing a sum of squares, you're maximizing LL.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Yes. Notice the function returns `-loglik` which handles this.

Comment: @felix Just a remark - I once had a problem which shared the same symptoms as yours, but the cause was totally different. It turned out that I had a bug in my gradient function so when I passed it in the the routine via the `jac` parameter, the routine could not work. The errors were cryptic and it was only upon re-inspecting my code that I identified the bug. That said, the answer below that uses `Nelder-Mead` really helped because it could optimize without the gradient, and gave the correct answer for me, helping me realize that the issue was with the bug in my gradient function.

Comment: Could someone also explain what *precision loss* is the warning referring to? I find it very obscure.

Comment: It seems like there is an answer here https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2004/scipy-optimize-fmin-bfgs-desired-error-not-necessarily-achieved-due-to-precisi

Comment: You may have found yourself in a similar situation to myself. I am trying to optimize some function which has a minium value around 500. While it claims to have had problems converging (warnings about precision, success=False) it actually has converged. I manually checked a few cases. Alternatively switch to a different method. 'Nelder-Mead' (Simplex) doesn't use gradient information, and so the warnings may go away, if they are related to this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I copied your example and tried a little bit. Looks like if you stick with BFGS solver, after a few iteration the `mu+ alpha * r` will have some negative numbers, and that's how you get the RuntimeWarning.

The easiest fix I can think of is to switch to Nelder Mead solver.

```
res = minimize(loglikelihood, (0.01, 0.1,0.1), method = 'Nelder-Mead',args = (atimes,))
```

And it will give you this result:

```
28.3136498357
  status: 0
    nfev: 159
 success: True
     fun: 27.982451280648817
       x: array([ 0.01410906,  0.68346023,  0.90837568])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 92
```

Comment: Thank you! Any intuition as to why/when Nelder-Mead would be a better choice than BGFS?

Comment: But be aware that just because `Nelder-Mead` thinks it terminated successfully doesn't necessarily mean that it did indeed find the minimum. In my application it was still way off at times...

Answer (score 14):

Another solution (that worked for me) is to scale your function (and gradients) to values closer to 0. For example, my problem came up when I had to evaluate a log-likelihood of 60k points. This meant that my log-likelihood was a very large number. Conceptually, the log-likelihood was a very very spikey function.

The gradients started off large (to climb this spikey mountain), and then became moderately small, but never less than the default `gtol` parameter in the BGFS routine (which is the threshold that all gradients must be below for termination). Also, at this time I had essentially arrived at the correct values (I was using generated data so I knew the true values).

What was happening was that my gradients were approx. 60k * `average individual gradient value`, and even if the `average individual gradient value` was small, say less than 1e-8, 60k * 1e-8 > `gtol`. So I was never satisfying the threshold even though I had arrived at the solution.

Conceptually, because of this very spikey mountain, the algorithm was making small steps, but stepping *over* the true minimum and never achieved `average individual gradient << 1e-8` which implies my gradients never went under `gtol`.

Two solutions:

1) Scale your log-likelihood and gradients by a factor, like `1/n` where `n` is the number of samples.

2) Scale your `gtol`: for example `"gtol": 1e-7 * n`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your way around the problem. I am still wondering however, why it cannot converge without rescaling? If I understand it right, your solution is equivalent just to scaling up gtol. Why could not it achieve the required precision even with the true log likelihood?

Answer (score 6):

Facing the same warning, I solved it by rewriting the log-likelihood function to get `log(params)` and `log(data)` as arguments, instead of params and data.

Thus, I avoid using `np.log()` in the likelihood function or Jacobian, if possible.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like a very good idea for the case when the parameter values have completely different scales, like in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Watch out for negative values of the log() function, resolve them and tell the optimizer that they are bad, by adding a penalty:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def loglikelihood(params, data):
    (mu, alpha, beta) = params
    tlist = np.array(data)
    r = np.zeros(len(tlist))
    for i in xrange(1,len(tlist)):
        r[i] = math.exp(-beta*(tlist[i]-tlist[i-1]))*(1+r[i-1])
    loglik = -tlist[-1]*mu
    loglik += alpha/beta*sum(np.exp(-beta*(tlist[-1]-tlist))-1)
    argument = mu + alpha * r
    limit = 1e-6
    if np.min(argument) < limit:
        # add a penalty for too small argument of log
        loglik += np.sum(np.minimum(0.0, argument - limit)) / limit
        # keep argument of log above the limit
        argument = np.maximum(argument, limit)
    loglik += np.sum(np.log(argument))
    return -loglik

atimes = [ 148.98894201,  149.70253172,  151.13717804,  160.35968355,
        160.98322609,  161.21331798,  163.60755544,  163.68994973,
        164.26131871,  228.79436067]
a= 0.01
alpha = 0.5
beta = 0.6
print loglikelihood((a, alpha, beta), atimes)

res = minimize(loglikelihood, (0.01, 0.1,0.1), method = 'BFGS',args = (atimes,))
print res
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late but I do 3 optimizations in series.  First I use a Nelder-Mead to get close.  Without first getting close, I get way too many overflow errors. I then copy res.x to the starting parameters for the next optimizing routine.  I have found that Powell is most reliable and it usually does a pretty good job.  BUT, I then do another minimization using Nelder-Mead again to avoid falling in to local minimums.
Usually, there isn't much improvement after using the Powell minimization.

Comment: This looks like a good reason for the optimization routines to be improved!