# Warning using SciPy fmin_bfgs() on regularized data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I'm using the next `cost()` and `gradient()` regularized functions:

```
def cost(theta, x, y, lam):
    theta = theta.reshape(1, len(theta))
    predictions = sigmoid(np.dot(x, np.transpose(theta))).reshape(len(x), 1)

    regularization = (lam / (len(x) * 2)) * np.sum(np.square(np.delete(theta, 0, 1)))

    complete = -1 * np.dot(np.transpose(y), np.log(predictions)) \
           - np.dot(np.transpose(1 - y), np.log(1 - predictions))
    return np.sum(complete) / len(x) + regularization


def gradient(theta, x, y, lam):
    theta = theta.reshape(1, len(theta))
    predictions = sigmoid(np.dot(x, np.transpose(theta))).reshape(len(x), 1)

    theta_without_intercept = theta.copy()
    theta_without_intercept[0, 0] = 0
    assert(theta_without_intercept.shape == theta.shape)
    regularization = (lam / len(x)) * np.sum(theta_without_intercept)

    return np.sum(np.multiply((predictions - y), x), 0) / len(x) + regularization
```

With these functions and `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs()` I'm getting next output ( which is almost correct ):

```
Starting loss value: 0.69314718056 
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 0.208444
         Iterations: 8
         Function evaluations: 51
         Gradient evaluations: 39
7.53668131651e-08
Trained loss value: 0.208443907192
```

Formula for Reguarization below. If I comment regularized inputs above `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs()` works well, and returns local optimum correctly.

Any ideas why?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After additional comments , I updated cost and gradient regularization (in the code above). But this warning still appear (new outputs above). `scipy check_grad` function return next value: 7.53668131651e-08.

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm using set [UCI Machine Learning](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php) `Iris` data. And based on Classification model `One-vs-All` training first resuls for `Iris-setosa`.

Comment: What is the value of lam? In your cost function, I think it should rather be (lam / len(x) / 2).

Comment: Lambda for Reg. is 1. I attached formula for Reg.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from including a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the parameters you are passing to `fmin_bfgs` and the expected result.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin hey, I added source with data set and values.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767191/scipy-is-not-optimizing-and-returns-desired-error-not-necessarily-achieved-due

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in my calculus, where for some reason I sum `theta` values in regularization: `regularization = (lam / len(x)) * np.sum(theta_without_intercept)`. We don't need **np.sum** regularized value in this stage. That will produce avaregae regularization for each theta and next prediction loss. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Gradient method:

```
def gradient(theta, x, y, lam):
    theta_len = len(theta)
    theta = theta.reshape(1, theta_len)

    predictions = sigmoid(np.dot(x, np.transpose(theta))).reshape(len(x), 1)

    theta_wo_bias = theta.copy()
    theta_wo_bias[0, 0] = 0

    assert (theta_wo_bias.shape == theta.shape)
    regularization = np.squeeze(((lam / len(x)) *
                  theta_wo_bias).reshape(theta_len, 1))

    return np.sum(np.multiply((predictions - y), x), 0) / len(x) + regularization
```

Output:

```
Starting loss value: 0.69314718056 
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.201681
         Iterations: 30
         Function evaluations: 32
         Gradient evaluations: 32
7.53668131651e-08
Trained loss value: 0.201680992316
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are trying to perform an L2-regularization, then you should modify the value in your cost function from

```
regularization = (lam / len(x) * 2) * np.sum(np.square(np.delete(theta, 0, 1)))
```

to

```
regularization = (lam / (len(x) * 2)) * np.sum(np.square(np.delete(theta, 0, 1)))
```

Also, the gradient part of the regularization should have the same shape as the vector of parameters `theta`. Hence I rather think the correct value would be

```
theta_without_intercept = theta.copy()
theta_without_intercept[0] = 0 #  You are not penalizing the intercept in your cost function, i.e. theta_0
assert(theta_without_intercept.shape == theta.shape)
regularization = (lam / len(x)) * theta_without_intercept
```

Otherwise, the gradient won't be correct. You can then check that your gradient is correct by using [**`scipy.optimize.check_grad()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html) function.

Comment: Hey, I updated my `cost` and `grad` function, but still facing this warning( I also used `scipy check_grad` function which returns next value: 7.53668131651e-08.